# Python, list condition in range

Tags: python, list

I need help to search a value in a range inside a list

```
list.append((5,range(10,15)))
if (5,12) in list :
    Print("yes")
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more clearly? Your example snippet isn't very helpful because it isn't valid Python syntax. Can you show an example input and your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `all`

**Ex:**

```
l = (5,range(10,15))
check = (5,12)
if all([check[0] == l[0] and check[1] in l[1]]):
    print("Ok")
```

**Output:**
**Ok**

Answer (score 0):

Make the second range as a list and you can do it this way-

```
result =  any(elem in list1  for elem in list2)
```

where result is `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
mylist = []
mylist.extend(list(range(10, 15)) + [5])

check_list = [5, 12]

if all([z in mylist for z in check_list]):
    print('yes')
```

Output:

`yes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list_1 = []
for i in range(10,15):
    list_1.append((5,i))
if (5,12) in list_1:
    print("yes")
```

If list_1 not an existing list you can do like this:

```
list_1 = [(5,i) for i in range(10,15)]
```